# Why do women wave their hands in front of the Shabbos candles before making the bracha?

Tags: shabbat, minhag, candle-lighting

There seems to be a widespread custom among women to wave their hands in front of Shabbos candles before making a bracha on them. I have never seen men do this when lighting the Shabbos candles. Why do women do this?